# jquery show/hide buttons on same row not showing pretty - causing half hight during animation?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, show-hide

I am trying to show an Edit button and then sub buttons switch out when clicked.

The issue is during animation, both sections become half height. The might be a clash with the Bootstrap css, or some combination i have tried with the spans/divs. Cannot figure out.

Also I think slide animation might be using float which might have some impact.

Hoping can resolve with change to the html (either chaning divs/spans or other, order?), instead of some css override, if possible?

[Edit]

on click hide button and show some others

[cancel] [other] [save]

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1s8e5kj5/2/

css:

```
<div class="col-xs-9">
<div style="display:inline-block">
    <button class="btn btn-default" data-bind="click: TempRunFunction">run</button>
</div>
<span>
    <span id="view-edit">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="showEdit();">Edit</button>
    </span>
    <span id="view-edit-buttons" class="" style="display:none;">
        <button class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
        <button class="btn btn-warning">Arrange</button>
```

js

```
var speed = 1000;

function showEdit() {
  $('#view-edit').hide('slide', { direction: 'left' }, speed);
  $('#view-edit-buttons').show('slide', { direction: 'left' }, speed);
}

function hideEdit() {
  $('#view-edit').show('slide', { direction: 'left' }, speed);
```

css: none overridden bootstrap v3

ideally:

```
[Edit]
[Edi..[canc..
[Ed.[cancel] [ot..
[cancel] [other] [save]
```

many thanks

Comment: can you post your css here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `pull-left` class to buttons' container, and use `complete` function.

```
var speed = 1000;

function showEdit() {
    $('#view-edit').hide('slide', {direction: 'left'}, speed/4, function(){
        $('#view-edit-buttons').show('slide', {direction: 'left'}, speed);
    });
}

function hideEdit() {
    $('#view-edit-buttons').hide('slide', { direction: 'left' }, speed, function(){
        $('#view-edit').show('slide', {direction: 'left'}, speed/4);
    });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1s8e5kj5/4/

Comment: love it, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS:

```
#view-edit, #view-edit-buttons {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Solves the funky display effect the animation is adding to your `span`.

It would be worthwhile for you to test as thoroughly as possible in case this display issue occurs in more than one way.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add a `display:inline-block;` to the `span` wrapping both the things you are animating. I created a class called `btn-container` and applied it to the span wrapping both these things.

Next you should add this style:

```
#view-edit, #view-edit-buttons{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
}
```

...which helps position the button wrappers properly so the animations can work.

[See demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/1s8e5kj5/6/)